# Error on if command, object nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, null

I have this code:

```
if (self.leadObject != nil) {
    [result addObject:self.leadObject];
}
```

And sometimes app close with this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM
>   insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

The execution pass if command and try to add the object `self.leadObject` inside of `result` array although this object is `nil`.
Can someone explain this??

**Update**:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM
>   insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil' *** First throw call
>   stack: (0x2ca8af87 0x3a1e9c77 0x2c9a6f29 0x1777ff 0x177a6f 0x177b7f
>   0x1779df 0x17446d 0xa1cdd 0xa7933 0x46cad3 0x46cabf 0x47051b
>   0x2ca50e61 0x2ca4f581 0x2c99cdb1 0x2c99cbc3 0x33d28051 0x2ff68a31
>   0xadb45 0x3a785aaf) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException

Comment: What does the implementation of `self.leadObject` look like?

Comment: are you sure the crash is caused at this part? I'd recommend adding a log statemenent before `[result addObject:self.leadObject]` where you print the value of `self.leadObject`, just to make sure...

Comment: Please paste a copy of the stack trace from the crash log into your question.

Comment: Yes, execution stop in this line and I watch the object and it's nil

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2ca8af87 0x3a1e9c77 0x2c9a6f29 0x1777ff 0x177a6f 0x177b7f 0x1779df 0x17446d 0xa1cdd 0xa7933 0x46cad3 0x46cabf 0x47051b 0x2ca50e61 0x2ca4f581 0x2c99cdb1 0x2c99cbc3 0x33d28051 0x2ff68a31 0xadb45 0x3a785aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: please update your question rather than putting code / logs into the comments :)

Comment: A better wat to get the stack trace is to type "bt" in the debug console when the application stops in the debugger.  That gives symbols instead of a list of numbers.

Comment: I would suggest add the Exception BreakPoint and check where the crash is happening

Comment: Are you sure you aren't calling `insertObject:atIndex:` somewhere?

Comment: Yes, there isn't any call to insertObject:atIndex:

Comment: Please show the definition of the declared property `leadObject` if there is one, otherwise the ivar definition and the definition of the getter, if it is not synthesized.

Comment: I use another mobile with iOS 7 and work fine! I have iOS 8.0.2 version on my mobile. Can be problem of iOS version?

Comment: @property(nonatomic, strong) id<QTreeInsertable> leadObject;

Comment: QTreeInsertable is a own class

Comment: @RobertoGómez I´m having the same error with Qtree pod, did you fixed it?

Comment: @FernandoGarcíaCorrochano I used another library, because I couldn't solve the problem

Answer (score -2):

I suspect that you have not allocated your result object. Do so if you didn't and then Log the self.leadObject to make sure that it isn't an NSNull

```
if (self.leadObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@", self.leadObject);
    [result addObject:self.leadObject];
}
```

Comment: if leadObject were an NSNull object then there would be no error.